# What are the options to automate command line utilities using C?

Tags: c, linux

Are there any open source libraries or standard functions that allow a C program to interact with other command line programs (that for example may request user input).

Comment: My mistake. Removed comment.. :)

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

Comment: What command line programs are you thinking of?

Comment: @basile starynkevich, things like nano

Comment: Then indeed `expect` is a good answer. But you mind find it not very convenient to use; I suggest in that case to find alternative ways of doing (e.g. use some library instead of forking a `nano` process)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`expect` is a popular library for programmatically interacting with interactive programs (e.g. `ssh`). There's a port of it to C called [`libexpect`](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.4/expect/libexpect.3.html) which may do what you want. `expect` emulates a terminal, so it is particularly useful for applications that won't talk to simple pipes.